# How to add modal?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is my link in view.php file I want to show my form in modal when clicked in Add Player Button.How can I do that? I am using bootstrap in my template.

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_login" class="btn btn-primary"  href="backend/players/player">Add Player</a>
```

insertPlayer.php
This is my insert form I want to show my insert form in modal.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <table  class="form-horizontal">
                        <tr  class="form-group"><td>First Name</td><td><?php echo form_input($fname) ?></td></td></tr>
                        <tr class="form-group" ><td>Last Name</td><td><?php echo form_input($lname) ?></td></tr>
                        <tr class="form-group"><td>Address</td><td><?php echo form_textarea($address) ?></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to load insertPlayer.php in you model loaded in view.php?

Comment: @bablu Yes, I think he want that.

Comment: @Juno Jabin you can use iframe if I my understood is correct

Comment: @juno jabin what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, its working... :)

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Add Player</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         // Your form
         <form>
           First name:<br>
           <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
           Last name:<br>
           <input type="text" name="lastname">
          </form> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to fetch insert form from another page. not in a single page

Comment: use ajax to achieve insert, clicking on save button...  :)

Comment: Hi @JunoJabin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/287197 by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your form inside modal div tag like

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <form>
   First name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="firstname">
     <br>
   Last name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form> 
</div>
```

and call it like

```
<?php    
    include'insertPlayer.php';   
?> 
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_login" class="btn btn-primary"  href="backend/players/player">Add Player</a>
```

Comment: @JunoJabin make sure you linked bootstrap package, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Look at my edited answer, Use include to include your php file where modal present.

Comment: thanx its working but how the form is breaking apart... how can i wrapped it in a div with custom style. like custom height width

Comment: What do you mean by breaking apart? if its working than please vote up and accept. :-)